# simple URL rewrite using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to rewrite my current directory structure to create a friendly URL.

Directory Structure

Root Folder

- includes
- images
- css
- js
- partials
- pages
- Page 1

  - index.php
- Page 2
- Page 3
- Page 4

So the current URL path is www.example.com/page/page1, but what i would like is to have is www.example.com/page1. So the website can be placed Bitbucket to enable versioning.

Any help or links are hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following rule in `root/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1) Redirect from "/page/foobar" to "/foobar" #
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
#2)internally redirect "/foobar" to "/page/foobar" #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect `/page` to `/page/page` .

Comment: I've tested this by placing the code above in a new htaccess file in the root folder on my Mamp server but I get the ' internal server error'. Have I attempted this in the wrong way? Sorry, this is my first time setting up .htaccess

Comment: Is the rewrite module/mod-rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: i have just enabled mod-rewrite, and I'm still get the same error

Comment: Please check your server error log for information about the error

Comment: This is the error it shows   

[Sat May 14 13:33:23 2016] [error] [client 192.168.0.10] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: you  are getting  a rewrite loop error, this happens when an url rewrits to itself  or rules are not in order.post your full htaccess in the question.

Comment: I cleared all PHP defines, and I've added the s on pages, now it works a treat. Thanks..

How do i redirect the pages/page1/ to page1

Comment: You're a star. Where the best place to learn all .htaccess coding